# Перенос текста книги на странице

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Допустим, создаю страницу с текстом на 100 страниц и текст должен распределятся по табам, которые сам же саздает с помощью скриптов, и переключение по табом делается с помощью кнопок назад-вперед.

Как сделать перенос текста книги на странице в следующий таб автоматически? Как сделать переключение без перезагрузки страницы?

Answer (score 2):

1. Книги грузим в БД (таблицы вида `{books:[book_id,book_name,book_descr/rating/author/etc]}` и `{book_pages:[book_id,page_num,text]}`)
2. Показываем описалово, оттуда ссылка типа `books.php?book_id=15`
3. При клике на номер страницы грузить нужную страницу аяксом

На заметку - есть в инете много функций, разбивающих текст по словам/символам. Для заливки вам надо поймать файл, заполнить инфу о книге(таблица *books*), а текст разбить на ~1800 знаков по словам (это А4) и постранично запихнуть в таблицу *book_pages*.

*ЗЫ: Готовое вам вряд ли напишут, это не 3 строки.*

*ЗЗЫ: Советую поискать готовую реализацию, такое вполне может быть.*